# Writing to SQLite DB from RecycleView Adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a Main view with one RecyclerView (category_view) in it and another RecyclerView (task_view) in each ViewHolder in category_view. So each Category has several Tasks in it. Data are populated from SQLite DB, I have tables for Categories and Tasks. Also I specified Parcelable for both Category and Task data classes.

Currently I pass a Cursor with Categories table from MainActivity to CategoriesRecyclerAdapter + Database itself. Then in CategoriesRecyclerAdapter I make another Cursor and pass it to TasksRecyclerAdapter.

Actions in nested RecycleView Tasks (checkbox tick) cause changes in both Categories and Tasks SQLite tables.

My question is - how to pass data between these nested adapters without passing whole DB link or DB Open Helper to every ViewHolder?

So currently I'm passing a link to mDb = mDbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(), so each Adapter can access it. Now I need to write data to DB, so I can pass either 2 links or 1 link to DBOpenHelper and open DB in each class.viewHolder. I'm not sure that opening a DB in each ViewHolder is a best and optimal solution. Can anyone suggest another solution or confirm that it's ok?

```
\\Main Activity: make a cursor and pass it to CategoriesRecyclerAdapter
...
private void getCategoriesFromDB() {
    mDb = mDbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final Cursor categoryCursor = mDb.query(CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME, 
    null, null, null, null, null, null);
    mCategoryRecyclerAdapter.changeCursor(categoryCursor, mDb);
}

\\CategoryRecyclerAdapter:
...
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (mCursor != null)
        mCursor.close();
    mCursor = cursor;
    populateColumnPositions();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    mDb = db;
}

...
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(i);

    String selection = TaskEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " = ?";
    String selectionArgs[] = {Integer.toString(mId)};
    final Cursor taskCursor = mDb.query(TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, 
          selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    LinearLayoutManager tasksLayoutManager = new               LinearLayoutManager(viewHolder.mHolderView.getContext());

    TaskRecyclerAdapter taskRecyclerAdapter = new               TaskRecyclerAdapter(viewHolder.mHolderView.getContext(), null, mDb);

    RecyclerView recyclerTasks =                viewHolder.mHolderView.findViewById(R.id.list_tasks);
    recyclerTasks.setLayoutManager(tasksLayoutManager);
    recyclerTasks.setAdapter(taskRecyclerAdapter);

    taskRecyclerAdapter.changeCursor(taskCursor);

}
```

Comment: Why do the adapters need to handle a database responsibility? An adapter should only know how to bind data to a view. Also, it would be better to take off data parsing to another class, put the parsed data into an array list and send it to the adapter. Also, closing and opening the database has performance. So the solution to the problem? [Thread safe SQLite instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888288/9968399)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Taseer. Through your link I found a good example of "how to do it right" - https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/, restructuring my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally a bad idea.  You'd ideally want to pass a listener to your adapter, and listen for events in your fragment/activity.  From their, you should be using a viewmodel/presenter to communicate with a database layer to make the updates.  Based on the result of the operation, success/failure, you can update your adapter with notifyItemChanged, or if adventurous go for a databiniding solution and just update your adapter's data model.