# Sqlite Database context android

Tags: java, android

I have created a Database class file to use SQLite db in Android app. Since I am beginner and I am having problem understanding what should i put in context when I instantiate Database class to another class
The database code is as follows:

```
public Database(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        database=getWritableDatabase();
```

How can I instantiate it to an another class. When doing instantiation Database db = new Database();
what should be put under context

Comment: Supply your Activity context like `Database db = new Database(MainActivity.this);`. It should be an Activity context not a Class context.

Comment: Create a Singleton database class that takes in the application context. You can get [idea from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888288/9968399).

Comment: its showing Main activity is not an enclosing class

Comment: I want to instantiate to a nonactivity class

Comment: Then transfer your context from your activity class to nonactivity class.

Comment: @L2_Paver how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android docs on Context.

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

So when you create a `View` you need to pass `Context` to it, but why? What your `View` will loose if it is not passed `Context`. Your `View` will loose the ability to access system resources. For eg suppose there is a `Drawable` that is to be set as background of your `View`, without context your `View` cannot access that `Drawable`.

```
public class MyView extends View {

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Drawable d = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);  //without context IDE will give error cannot resolve getDrawable(int).
    }
}
```

So when you create a `View` you pass `Activity Context` to it, because your `View` is tied to your `Activity`. It should not outlive `Activity`.

```
MyView myView = new MyView(this);
```

You can use `this` as Context because your `Activity` extends from `ContextThemeWrapper`, which extends from `ContextWrapper` which extends from  `Context`.

Now if you want to create a `Database`, and if your app has multiple `Activities` which need access to `DB`, then your `DB` should outlive the `Activity` which created `DB` instance, so in this case you should use `Application Context` to create `DB`.

Even if you have a single `Activity` app, then also your `DB` should outlive your `Activity`, because your `Activity` will be restarted on every `Rotation`. But your `Application` is not. So here also you should pass `Application Context`.

As a general rule, think of `Context` as the lifetime for your newly created object, For `DB` you generally want `Application` lifetime.

To make it clear consider an example : Your app starts with `Activity A`, which download large `Bitmap` form network, creates a `DB` instance on its `Context` and saves `Bitmap` to the `DB`. After that your `Activity A` starts `Activity B` and `A` is finished. Now your `Activity A` is no longer required and should be garbage collected. But your `DB` is still alive on its `Context` so `A` will not be gc'ed and will result in Memory Leak.

Finally as Naresh as already pointed in his answer you should make your `DB` a `Singleton`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the application context, which will ensure that you don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
See this article for more information: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Make your SqliteDB class a singleton as -

```
private static Database sInstance;

public static synchronized Database getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new Database(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private ChatSQliteDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.v("SQLTVer", "ver "+DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new Class

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MySuperApplication extends Application {
    private static Application instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

It will generate the context automatically. So wherever its asked we can write Database db= new Database(MySuperApplication.getContext());

Comment: `Database db= new Database(MySuperApplication.getContext())` will give you new instance of `DB` every time, your `DB` should be a `Singleton`.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate it to RandomActivity class, you should put:

```
Database db = new Database(this);
```

or

```
Database db = new Database(RandomActivity.this);
```

Comment: Database db =new Database(Combiner.this);. I tried this  but its showing Database(android.content,Context) in Database cannot be applied to (com.example.data.Combiner)

Answer (score 0):

First you declare context globally in your Activity:

```
Context context = this
```

then make a method/function in your nonactivity class that require a parameter context.

```
class YOUR_CLASS{

    public void YOUR_METHOD(Context context){       //method with require context parameter

         Database db = new Database(context);  //supplied the context from your activity
    }
}
```

then call YOUR_METHOD from YOUR_CLASS in  your Activity with supplied context.

```
new YOUR_CLASS().YOUR_METHOD(context); //supply context on your method
```